# Removal of the outer boundary of black and white image

Tags: matlab

I wrote this code

```
y=imread('..........bmp');
bw=im2bw(y);
b=bwboundaries(bw);
boundry=b{1};
imshow(bw);
hold on;
plot(boundry(:,2),boundry(:,1),'g');
```

I obtained this image http://postimage.org/image/91xxambx9/

Now I need to remove the outer boundary in green color without any effect on the details inside this boundary , is this possible in Matlab ? If it is possible how can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Well, this outer boundary in green color is caused by the `plot` command. So just remove it.

```
y=imread('..........bmp');
bw=im2bw(y);
b=bwboundaries(bw);
boundry=b{1};
imshow(bw);
```

Comment: i plotted it as a boundary detection ,but if i remove it as your answer this will remove it from this figure only , but not will be removed from the original image. i want to remove it from original image also not from the displayed figure only . i wish that my question is obvious.

Comment: @ruaa, in that case consider using the function inpaint_nans http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4551

Comment: i didn't understand the function in mathworks . i want any simple code .please , i am just newbie to matlab